# Heroku React App Behaving Differently: laptop vs Desktop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cross-platform, cloudinary

I have a simple MERN stack app that displays images from Cloudinary. For example, a search for "shoes" will display any images in my Cloudinary database that are tagged with "shoes".

To load more images, I have a window event that will activate my "loadMore" function when the scrollbar is at the bottom of the browser window. The function works perfectly on my Mac Desktop, however when I visit the site from my laptop, it loads duplicate images. I logged the scrolling events and they are working fine on both devices. I'm just not sure why the behavior is different across those two devices.

---

Scroll Event:

```
  var totalPageHeight = document.body.scrollHeight; 

    // @var int scrollPoint
    var scrollPoint = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;

    // check if we hit the bottom of the page
    if(scrollPoint >= totalPageHeight)
    {
        if(nextCursor){
          handleLoadMoreButtonClick()
        }
    }
}
```

Load More Images Event:

```
  console.log(`Prior to loading more images, next cursor is :  ${nextCursor}`)
  if(nextCursor){
    console.log("LOADING MORE IMAGES!!!!!!")
    const responseJson = await searchImages(query, nextCursor);
    setImageList((currentImageList) => [
      ...currentImageList,
      ...responseJson.resources,
    ]);
    setNextCursor(responseJson.next_cursor);
    setNumImage(imageList.length+responseJson.resources.length)
  }
  
};
```

I have checked to make sure that the scroll event function is working, and it is properly detecting when the scrollbar reaches the bottom of the page.
For some odd reason, it just loads many duplicates of the original images when I visit the site on my laptop, even though the variables such as nextCursor etc are correct.

Comment: MacOS handles scroll events differently than windows. `handleLoadMoreButtonClick` probably runs multiple times with the same cursor

Comment: @KonradLinkowski interesting! Are you able to expand on that a bit more/have any resources I should look into for this? Thanks for the input. Also, it still works on my iMac, just not Mac laptop and iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

If the scroll function is fired multiple times, you can use a local variable `isScrollEventFired = false`, set it to `true` inside your scroll function & set it to `false` again when state is updated and `return` if `isScrollEventFired` is `true` inside your scroll function